# Regex: Not in a List - Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Is there a way that I could include into my expression the ability for me to check if the item isn't in a list.

I have the Situation where I have a list of words:

```
listA = ["Abc","Def","etc"]
```

What I want to do is to perform the match where it matched the Regular Expression, but the match didn't contain any of the words given in the list?

I can do this without regular expressions, but wondering if there was an inbuilt way in Python to do this.

For example:

```
names = ["David","John","Bob"]
x = "From John@email.com Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008"

y = re.findall([NOT in Names]+'\S+@\S+',x)
```

The expected output will should be an empty list.  (because it contains John)
If the email above was `will@email.com` then I would like the output to be

```
['will@email.com']
```

Comment: Can you show the expression and the expected output please?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will add it in now.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```
names = ["David","John","Bob"]
x = """From will@email.com Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008
       From mike@email.com Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008"""
y = [m[0] for m in re.findall('((\S+)@\S+)',x) if m[1] not in names]
-> ['will@email.com', 'mike@email.com']
```